# Deno aggregate with mongoDB using $lookup and $project

Tags: database, mongodb, lookup, deno

I am trying to connect two tables using aggregate in MongoDB and Deno using this library:

https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.20.1

According to documentation, this is how we can use it.

```
// aggregation
const docs = await users.aggregate([
  { $match: { username: "many" } },
  { $group: { _id: "$username", total: { $sum: 1 } } },
]);
```

But there is no facility or scope to connect two different tables using **$lookup** and **$project**
Is there any other way to use lookup and project together in Deno?

Answer (score 1):

This is how aggregation works in Deno and deno_mongo.

```
var data = Report.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "senderId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "sender",
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "reportedId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "reported",
        },
      },
      { $match: { status : 1 } },
      { $sort: { createdAt: 1} },
      { $skip: 10 },
      { $limit: 5 },
    ]).toArray();
```